# Using Span<T> in a C++/CLR Project

Tags: .net, c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

I have a C# project and a C++/CLR project in Visual Studio 2019.  Both are targeting .NET 4.8.  I'm trying to use a `Span<byte>` that gets passed from the C# project to the C++/CLR project.

Since both assemblies are targeting .NET 4.8, I'm using the `System.Memory (4.5.2)` NuGet package and its dependencies (`System.Buffers`, `System.Numerics.Vectors`, `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`).  I have the same assemblies referenced in the C# project and the C++/CLR project.

In the C++/CLR project, I'm trying to access the span like so:
`System::Span<unsigned char> span = pixelBuffer->Span;`

I get this error on that line:
`Foo.cpp(1544): error C2079: 'System::Span<unsigned char>::Enumerator::_span' uses undefined class 'System::Span<unsigned char>'`

This doesn't make sense to me, since I can see `System.Span<T>` in the System.Memory.dll that the C++/CLR project is referencing.

I did find an open issue, but they are only getting warnings, not errors:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1017965/systemreadonlyspan-deprecated-warning-using-ccli.html